# pinging ec2 instance from ansible

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2, ansible

I have an ec2 amazon linux running which I can ssh in to using:

```
ssh -i "keypair.pem" ec2-user@some-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com
```

but when I try to ping the server using ansible I get:

```
testserver | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

I'm using the following hosts file:

```
testserver ansible_ssh_host=some-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com ansible_ssh_user=ec2-user ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/Users/me/playbook/key-pair.pem
```

and running the following command to run ansible:

```
ansible testserver -i hosts -m ping -vvvvv
```

The output is:

```
<some-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com> ESTABLISH SSH CONNECTION FOR USER: ec2-user
<some-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com> SSH: ansible.cfg set ssh_args: (-o)(ControlMaster=auto)(-o)(ControlPersist=60s)
<some-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com> SSH: ANSIBLE_PRIVATE_KEY_FILE/private_key_file/ansible_ssh_private_key_file set: (-o)(IdentityFile="/Users/me/playbook/key-pair.pem")
<some-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com> SSH: ansible_password/ansible_ssh_pass not set: (-o)(KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no)(-o)(PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey)(-o)(PasswordAuthentication=no)
<some-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com> SSH: ANSIBLE_REMOTE_USER/remote_user/ansible_user/user/-u set: (-o)(User=ec2-user)
<some-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com> SSH: ANSIBLE_TIMEOUT/timeout set: (-o)(ConnectTimeout=10)
<some-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_common_args: ()
<some-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com> SSH: PlayContext set ssh_extra_args: ()
<some-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com> SSH: found only ControlPersist; added ControlPath: (-o)(ControlPath=/Users/me/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r)
<some-ip.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com> SSH: EXEC ssh -C -vvv -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s -o 'IdentityFile="/Users/me/playbook/key-pair.pem"' -o KbdInteractiveAuthentication=no -o PreferredAuthentications=gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey -o PasswordAuthentication=no -o User=ec2-user -o ConnectTimeout=10 -o ControlPath=/Users/me/.ansible/cp/ansible-ssh-%h-%p-%r ec2-52-18-106-35.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com '/bin/sh -c '"'"'( umask 22 && mkdir -p "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462096401.65-214839021792201 `" && echo "` echo $HOME/.ansible/tmp/ansible-tmp-1462096401.65-214839021792201 `" )'"'"''
testserver | UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": false,
    "msg": "Failed to connect to the host via ssh.",
    "unreachable": true
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: are you sure you don't have typo in the hostname? I can't connect to `ec2-52-18-106-35.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com` using `ssh` either.

Comment: Yes definitely got the right host name. It's publicly accessible here and I've just double checked I can ssh in using the address above http://ec2-52-18-106-35.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Comment: Which version of Ansible are you using?

Comment: Just to know, are you able to ping ec2-52-18-106-35.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com and telnet on 22, from your machine and you have used "ec2-52-18-106-35.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com" in your hosts file?

Comment: I've restarted the instance so I have a new address: http://ec2-52-48-83-57.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com/ this is publicly accessible and pingable but I can't telnet to it

Comment: You mean you cannot connect to the host on 22?
I mean, what does "telnet ec2-52-48-83-57.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com 22" return? and did you have the SSH port open for your local machine?

Comment: Yes I cannot telnet on port 22 - it returns -telnet: connect to address 52.48.83.57: Operation timed out
-telnet: Unable to connect to remote host. I can ssh fine ssh -i "my-key-pair.pem" ec2-user@ec2-52-48-83-57.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com

Comment: "and did you have the SSH port open for your local machine" why would I need to open the ssh port for my local machine? ssh'ing to any other remote server, including aws is not an issue for me. Connecting via ansible seems to be the issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110756/discussion-between-ravitezu-and-mike-rifgin).

Comment: I am not sure, if that help you but it help me in the past by setting control_path = %(directory)s/%%h-%%r in the ansible.cfg

Comment: That doesn't seem to help either

Answer (score 5):

Try this Solution it worked fine for me

```
ansible ipaddress  -m ping  -i inventory -u ec2-user
```

where inventory is the host file name.

```
inventory :    
[host]
xx.xx.xx.xx
[host:vars]
ansible_user=ec2-user
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/location of your pem file/filename.pem
```

I was facing the problem as I didn't give the location of the host file I was referring to.

Answer (score 1):

This is what my host file looks like.
**[apache]** is the group of hosts on which we are going to install apache server.
**ansible_ssh_private_key_file** should be the path of the dowloaded .pem file to access your instances. In my case both instances have same credentials.

```
[apache]
50.112.133.205 ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
54.202.7.87 ansible_ssh_user=ubuntu
[apache:vars]
ansible_user=ubuntu
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/hashimyousaf/Desktop/hashim_key_oregon.pem
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem, and reading through[Troubleshooting Connecting to Your Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectingMindTerm) helped me. Specifically, I was pinging an Ubuntu instance from an Amazon-Linux instance but forgot to change the connection username from "ec2-user" to "ubuntu"!

Answer (score 0):

You have to change the hosts file and make sure you have the correct username

```
    test2 ansible_ssh_host=something.something.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com ansible_ssh_user=theUser
```

'test2' - is the name I have give to the ssh machice on my local ansible hosts file

'ansible_ssh_host=something.something.eu-west-1.compute.amazonaws.com' - This is the connection to the ec2 instance

'ansible_ssh_user=theUser' - The user of the instance. (Important)

1. 'ssh' into your instance
2. [theUser@Instance:] make sure you copy the 'theUser' into the hosts and place as the 'ansible_ssh_user' variable

then try to ping it.

If this does not work, check if you have rights to the ICMP packeting in the amazon aws enabled.

Answer (score 0):

```
Worked for me ->

vi inventory

[hosts]
serveripaddress ansible_ssh_user=ec2-user
[hosts:vars]
ansible_user=ec2-user
ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/someuser/ansible1.pem

chmod 400 ansible1.pem

ansible -i inventory hosts -m ping -u ec2-user
```

Comment: Code-only answers are generally considered low-quality answers on Stack Overflow. This answer could be improved with an explanation as to how this solves OP's problem presented in the question. I would also recommend using separate code blocks for code and file contents, and putting information text outside of the code blocks.